# JDBC driver not using latest TLS offered version when connecting to a service

Tags: oracle, jdbc, tls1.2, tls1.3

JDBC driver not using latest TLS offered version when connecting to a service.

When connecting to said service, the server return multiple TLS versions that it support (1.0, 1.1 and 1.2). Yes, I know.... lol

We did try with multiple JDBC driver version (version 12 and up to 19), but as soon it try to connect to the server, as it see's that version 1.0 or 1.1 is available, it stop there and does not look for 1.2 . Therefore we get an error and it does not connect.

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: IO Error The server
> selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences
> [TLS13, TLS12], Authentication lapse 0 ms.

For further testing, we did enabled back 1.0 and 1.1 in our JVM (client) and the connection was successful.

So my question here is: Why does the JDBC driver does not continue to look for the latest TLS version (We did receive 1.2 that our drive does support) ? Is there an order that need to be respected ? Should the server answer with 1.2 then 1.1 then 1.0 ?

P.S: Here is what I get from the server when I try to check the versions with OpenSSL

```
SSL handshake has read 5192 bytes and written 358 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 7106B54533BDC4FA3A2E1077DC84170819381<EDITED>
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: EC782616A72BBA4A0890FB98EC1CE5A07B1F<EDITED>
    Start Time: 1649774530
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

**P.S**:
We did try the testing from our workstations using DataGrip and the same JDBC versions and we get the same behaviour.

Comment: Which database are you connecting to, which driver (and version) are you using, and what Java version are you using?

Comment: JDK 11.0.11 and we tried all JDBC version in between 12c and 19. As for the end point database. I do not know. It is a SQL, but I can't tell you the product name.

Comment: Given you mention 12c and 19, you're using Oracle. In any case, the error message says that the server offered only TLS 1.0, so I guess your OpenSSL check wasn't against Oracle, but against some other service (e.g. a HTTP server) on the same host.

Comment: With default settings, Oracle JDBC should use the latest TLS version supported by both the JVM and the database. If we have JDK 8 and a 19c database, both should support TLS 1.2.
Is it possible that some none-default settings are limiting the TLS version?
On the DB side: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netrf/parameters-for-the-sqlnet.ora.html#GUID-A2A81CEE-162D-4602-8315-990C8CC9E9E2
On the JDBC side: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_SSL_VERSION